# can forms be sent in MIME format

Tags: html

I am trying to send a form via email in MIME format. However the input tag is replaced with square brackets, ie.

`< input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>`  ==> [Submit]

I have tried replacing the input tag with the button tag and I got plain text, ie.

`< button type="submit"> Submit < /button>` ==> Submit

I read that when using MIME, one should, "code like its 1996". Can input fields and buttons be sent via e-mail in MIME format? If yes, the how do I get the buttons to display? If not, do you know of a work around?

My Content-Type is set to html/text. I have tried `multipart/alternative`, `multipart/mixed`, and `application/javascript`(because the form will have javascript in it) and I do not have a Content-ID specified. The emails are being viewed in outlook 2010.

Comment: I think they are considered as a security risk in some mail clients, What about just emailing the link to the actual form instead of emailing the form itself ?

Comment: well the idea is for the recipient to be able to fill out the form and submit it through the e-mail it self, without the need of visiting a website.

Comment: I think you need to read up on what [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) is … it doesn't mean HTML formatted email.

Comment: @ Quentin: yes I do, and I am. but for the sake of my question I was trying to limit the scope of it to html formatted emails... i think

Answer (score 3):

Support for [HTML forms embedded in email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/entry/674/using-forms-in-email/) is generally quite poor. Support for JavaScript embedded in email is as close to nil as makes no difference.

You are much better off emailing a link to a webpage containing the form instead.

Comment: @I-O — That's entirely about accepting file uploads without performing proper checks on them. There is nothing specific about (or any mention of) forms embedded in email there. For that matter, the question doesn't mention file uploads, just forms.